# Metadata API for IBM cloud storage object S3 API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, object-storage, cloud-storage

I have checked for Metadata API for IBM cloud storage object S3 API but unable to find any information related to it.Is there any on documentation on model definition of IBM cloud storage object S3 API? if there is any,please provide link of it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reference to the 'Cloud Storage Object API', I can guess you might be working with an on-premises installation of IBM COS. Not sure what you mean by 'Metadata API'.  `HEAD` requests can be used to retrieve an object's headers, where any custom metadata would be stored.  Additionally, it is often good application design to store metadata in a database for more efficient querying.